# How do I speed up my query?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm attempting to run a query over a very large dataset, although due to my lack of expertise in oracle, I can't seem to speed it up and the query takes a very long time, because there are a lot of rows of data. I attached the explain plan to show what exactly is doing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
select 
    a.customer_id, 
    c.vm_mor, 
    c.vm_id, 
    d.license_id, 
    e.product, 
    f.guest_os_id 
from 
    customers a, 
    vm_groups b, 
    vms c, 
    vm_licenses d, 
    licenses e, 
    vm_compute_histories f 
where 
    a.customer_id = b.customer_id 
    and b.vm_group_id = c.vm_group_id 
    and c.vm_id = d.vm_id 
    and d.license_id = e.license_id
    and c.vm_id = f.vm_id 
order by 
    a.customer_id, vm_id

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3321561485

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                      |  7575 |   591K|    36  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY             |                      |  7575 |   591K|    36  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                |                      |  7575 |   591K|    35   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN               |                      |  1238 | 87898 |    17  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL      | LICENSES             |    45 |  1665 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     HASH JOIN              |                      |  1241 | 42194 |    14  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |      VIEW                  | index$_join$_002     |    46 |   368 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |       HASH JOIN            |                      |       |       |            |          |
|   8 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| XIF1VM_GROUPS        |    46 |   368 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| XPKVM_GROUPS         |    46 |   368 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |      HASH JOIN             |                      |  1241 | 32266 |    11  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL    | VMS                  |  1062 | 18054 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | XIE1VM_LICENSES      |  1241 | 11169 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL       | VM_COMPUTE_HISTORIES |  7780 | 70020 |    17   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("C"."VM_ID"="F"."VM_ID")
   3 - access("D"."LICENSE_ID"="E"."LICENSE_ID")
   5 - access("B"."VM_GROUP_ID"="C"."VM_GROUP_ID")
   7 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  10 - access("C"."VM_ID"="D"."VM_ID")

29 rows selected.
```

Here is the explain plan that was asked for:

this is the query:

```
SELECT a.customer_id,
         c.vm_mor,
         c.vm_id,
         d.license_id,
         e.product,
         f.guest_os_id
    FROM customers a,
         vms c,
         vm_licenses d,
         licenses e,
         vm_compute_histories f
   WHERE     EXISTS
                 (SELECT 'X'
                    FROM vm_groups b
                   WHERE     a.customer_id = b.customer_id
                         AND c.vm_group_id = b.vm_group_id)
         AND c.vm_id = d.vm_id
         AND d.license_id = e.license_id
         AND c.vm_id = f.vm_id
ORDER BY a.customer_id, c.vm_id
/
```

The Plan:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1991801996

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                      |  2354 |   144K|    31  (13)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                    |                      |  2354 |   144K|    31  (13)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                       |                      |  2354 |   144K|    30  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                   |                      |   388 | 20952 |    15  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN                     |                      |   388 | 19400 |    15  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      SORT UNIQUE                  |                      |    46 |   368 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       VIEW                        | index$_join$_006     |    46 |   368 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |        HASH JOIN                  |                      |       |       |            |          |
|   8 |         INDEX FAST FULL SCAN      | XIF1VM_GROUPS        |    46 |   368 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |         INDEX FAST FULL SCAN      | XPKVM_GROUPS         |    46 |   368 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |      HASH JOIN                    |                      |   388 | 16296 |    12  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |       MERGE JOIN                  |                      |   388 |  9700 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| LICENSES             |    22 |   374 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |         INDEX FULL SCAN           | XPKLICENSES          |    22 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |        SORT JOIN                  |                      |   388 |  3104 |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |         INDEX FAST FULL SCAN      | XIE1VM_LICENSES      |   388 |  3104 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL           | VMS                  |   953 | 16201 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | XPKCUSTOMERS         |     1 |     4 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL              | VM_COMPUTE_HISTORIES |  5769 | 51921 |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("C"."VM_ID"="F"."VM_ID")
   4 - access("C"."VM_GROUP_ID"="B"."VM_GROUP_ID")
   7 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  10 - access("C"."VM_ID"="D"."VM_ID")
  14 - access("D"."LICENSE_ID"="E"."LICENSE_ID")
       filter("D"."LICENSE_ID"="E"."LICENSE_ID")
  17 - access("A"."CUSTOMER_ID"="B"."CUSTOMER_ID")

36 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: It looks okay to be honest. Do you need the ORDER BY?

Comment: You say that the data set is "very large".  Oracle is estimating that the query returns only 7575 rows.  How many rows does it actually return?  Your query does not have any predicates-- is that really what you want?  It very rarely makes sense to return a "very large" result set to a human.  Can you quantify "very long time"?  What is your target query response time?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: My Query returns 10,764 rows, Thanks for your advice, I just noticed something that won't work with this query.  I'm trying to get every license assigned to each vm while simueltaneously trying to a unique guest os id per unique vm. This query will not do that. I will post how I do it after I figure it out.

Comment: @marc_s I don't know how for SQL Server. but oracle optimizer rewrites your query and creates the explain plan and it doesn't matter if you use ANSI-92 or ANSI-89.

Comment: @zaratustra: even so - it makes the query much more **readable** if you use the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax (instead of this old SQL-89 style) - that alone is **worth the effort**

Comment: @marc_s of course, it's up to you. For me ANSI-89 is good enough I've been using it for about five years, it successfully helps me to reach my goals and I don't see any advantages ANSI-92 over ANSI-89, there are only subjective preferences. Many oracle guys use ANSI-89 in their work, I guess it's something like a habit. Also there were some problems in parsing ANSI-92 queries in previous releases, may be it comes from that time.

Comment: Can you post the output of `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'your sql_id', type => 'text') from dual;`?  Execution plans are only helpful to you if you understand your data and how it should be accessed.  The SQL Monitoring report will tell us estimates vs. actual, making it much easier to tell where the plan is going wrong.

Comment: yea no problem give me a bit though thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this, it may speed up your query

```
SELECT /*+ use_hash(a,b,c,d,e,f) */
```

use this SELECT statement in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing the explain plan to this SQL. I wasn't able to paste this as a comment, so I had to post it as an "answer". What I noticed from you query is that you never project on the values from table "b", so an EXISTS may help make things a bit faster...

Check it out:

```
  SELECT a.customer_id,
         c.vm_mor,
         c.vm_id,
         d.license_id,
         e.product,
         f.guest_os_id
    FROM customers a,
         vms c,
         vm_licenses d,
         licenses e,
         vm_compute_histories f
   WHERE     EXISTS
                 (SELECT 'X'
                    FROM vm_groups vm1
                   WHERE     a.customer_id = vm.customer_id
                         AND c.vm_group_id = vm.vm_group_id)
         AND c.vm_id = d.vm_id
         AND d.license_id = e.license_id
         AND c.vm_id = f.vm_id
ORDER BY a.customer_id, vm_id
```